# Reduce PHP memory usage when looping over all products in WooCommerce / Wordpress with LiteSpeed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, out-of-memory

I am working on a plugin for WooCommerce that creates an XML file containing all products from the store. The following code is used to fetch all products, which works fine in most cases.

```
$args = array(
    'status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'type'.  => array( 'simple', 'variable', 'bundle', 'composite' ),
    'offset' => $this->offset,
    'limit'  => $this->chunk_size,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

while ( count( $products ) ) {
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        $output .= $this->render_entry( $product );
    }

    if ( ! wp_using_ext_object_cache() ) {
        wp_cache_flush();
    }

    $args['offset'] += $this->chunk_size;
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
}
```

Even in a store with more than 20.000 products, this works just fine. However, when that store also uses **LiteSpeed Cache**, the memory usage will in increase every while-loop and result in:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted

- The memory limit is 1024M
- The cache is not flushed when using Object cache from LiteSpeed in this code, because that would ignore the purpose of a cache

Is there any way to reduce the PHP memory usage while keeping the memory limit at 1024M?

Comment: Why there are `$products = wc_get_products( $args );` called twice?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra the second wc_get_products gets the next batch of products (as the offset increases)

Comment: So, are you suggesting that the "LiteSpeed Cache" (whatever that is ...) would cause `wp_using_ext_object_cache` to return True?  If so, don't you need to do something to flush *that* cache?  Or, since one would ordinarily presume that "caches are supposed to be self-maintaining beasts," can you reliably set some kind of threshold for that external cache, and do it predictably?